# Website hosted on Firebase does not update

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I tried out Firebase hosting for the first time today, so I made a simple `create-react-app` application to host my website. I followed the instructions on Firebase step-by-step and decided to structure it like this: Before deploying, I run `npm run build`, to get the build version of my app. I set Firebase up so that when I deploy, it deploys from the `build` folder. However, when I make changes to the `src` folder and then save them and run `npm run build` command, and then deploy the `build` folder, my website hosted on Firebase doesn't change. Which is weird, because when I run `firebase serve`, my changes to `build` directory are visible on the local server.

Comment: maybe is a problem in your html, did you checked it first with a browser before doing the firebase deploy ?

Comment: As I said, I'm using create-react-app, so everything is automatically generated. By using the firebase serve command, firebase spins up a local server with the folder you chose to use as the deploy version of your application, which is build folder in this case. firebase serve command works perfectly and the local server has all the newest changes, but when I deploy the same folder to firebase hosting, the website shows only the very first version of my website, without any changes